# How may I create a package installer and extract the contents only in a specific folder

Tags: zip, installation, package, directory, extract

Edit: Oops my bad! I wasn't clear enough... I guess I need to explain more...

I need to create a package installer for my customers. I want them to extract and overwrite the contents only in their specific folder.

I don't want them to be able to extract the contents wherever they want to let them steal my work /or know what my files are all about.

So I was thinking maybe the installer could be created in a way to check for a file name inside the folder and after the file name has been recognized then it can be simply extracted and overwritten and if not then the operation will be cancelled.

Any Idea ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ Feign, the question is, how may I create a package installer and extract the contents only in a specific folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Windows...If the file name is recognised in the specified extraction folder, then it'll prompt you to either overwrite or cancel. - Either using Window's own extractor or something like 7Zip will achieve this.

Comment: I wan't clear enough.. sry... could you please read the first post again ? (I'm running Windows btw...)

Comment: Okay. - I may be misunderstanding your question a little still. - If you want to extract the contents within a packaged (zipped) file, but only want to select a certain folder, use 7Zip. - You can literally 'select' the folder and choose to only extract that element. Windows should also do it but it's not as good.

Comment: I've just re-read your edit. - So you want to provide a file but you want certain restrictions? - You can securely protect individual areas of a compressed file, should you want to but with the detail we've got - Why not just supply your customers **only** with the documents they need?

Comment: ok let me explain more... 1. I have some customers that need my upgrade package for their software  2. The  contents of the package has to be replaced with some of their old files. 3. The package contains some information that needs to be secured from being extracted anywhere else but that specific folder (cause it makes it difficult for amateur users to grab my files and sell them as their own package)

Comment: I can secure my installer easily using AutoPlay Media Studio or other programs but I'm not sure if 7zip could recognizethat specific folder automatically to extract the package because their program could have been installed in different drives...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I believe this might help:

https://superuser.com/questions/259353/7-zip-windows-7-make-extract-to-folder-default-on-double-click

Particularly Haiggoh's comment:

> 1.Start regedit as administrator
>    2.Open HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.7z
>    3.Under that key, expand the Shell sub-key
>    4.Set the (Default) value to the string extract
>    5.Create a new sub-key named extract
>    6.Set the (Default) value for the extract key to Extract to Folder
>    7.Create a new sub-key under extract named command
>    8.Set the (Default) value of the command key to:
>
> C:\ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7zG.exe x "%1" -o*   (you might have to a adjust
>   this to match the path of you 7zip installation)
>
> Instead of 7z with -aou like Justin Roettger suggested I ended up
>   using 7zG, because this way you can choose to overwrite if you like
>   just like extracting with the normal context menu.
>
> That's it! 7z files are now extracted to a folder with their own name
>   by double click. For other extensions like .rar and .zip you need to
>   repeat these steps for the according keys. (i.e.
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.rar and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\7-Zip.zip and so on)
>
> Oh and to clarify: It does work with multiple files selected as well.
>   No batch file need.

Have a read through the above and hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.